# Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate from same machine

Tags: ios, certificate, build-process, ios-provisioning

I am trying to create an IPA from my machine.

While creating an IPA I am getting the error "Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate".

I created the certificate and provisioning profiles, so all my code signing identities are on my machine. I'm able to run the app in device with the same certificate but unable to build the .ipa file.

I am creating the certificates with admin rights (not with agent rights). I am creating Development certificate (not an ad hoc certificate: for some reason I can't use ad hoc).

Comment: for testing purpose use development certificate. your .ipa file not able to install in other devices if your signing with distribution certificate.

Comment: Yes I realized the same after hell lot of RND,

apple keep changing its policies its becoming headache some times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I create IPA file with distribution certificate instead of development profile.

Comment: I am also facing the same error 'Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate'. I creating iPA using distribution provisioning file and distribution certificate. How your issue was resolved?