# Building Application for Archive from another developer on the same team procedure

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

What is the correct procedure for passing along an iOS project from one developer to another developer under the same team?  I receive the "Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets" message.  It states that "Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate..."

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ixkd.jpg

There are several links to similar topics in SO-
[Xcode 6 App Store submission fails with "Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717994/xcode-6-app-store-submission-fails-with-your-account-already-has-a-valid-ios-di)
[xcode 6 beta 2 issue with exporting ipa "Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438010/xcode-6-beta-2-issue-with-exporting-ipa-your-account-already-has-a-valid-ios-di)
[Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate from same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122888/your-account-already-has-a-valid-ios-distribution-certificate-from-same-machine)
[Error Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251970/error-your-account-already-has-a-valid-ios-distribution-certificate)

I am aware there are steps you need to follow when sharing projects, I however cannot seem to get them down.  Can anyone help in telling me the correct procedure for handling the project between developers on the same team?

Comment: Make the recipient go to the developers portal and download all missing assets manually, if you've already done that you might want to go through the signing settings and verify them manually.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on how you do it? @A-live

Comment: You'll need to check the developer certificate to be installed and not have duplicates at the keychain, the provisioning profiles to be installed if you don't want to rely on Xcode downloading it, verify the target settings for all build configurations and build scheme settings for Archiving. Try to use specific values at least for the release signing options rather than using automatic selection. When checking the target settings, make sure you check the dependent targets' settings as well (e.g. unit tests).