# "Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate” Xcode 6.4?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6.4

Error:

> You have a valid iOS Distribution certificate in the Member Center.
>   but it is not installed locally. If your signing identity is installed
>   on another Mac. you can export a developer profile on that Mac and
>   import it on this Mac. You can also revoke your current certificate
>   and request a new one.

I searched lot on this in StackOverflow but none of that worked for me.

What I tried is listed here:

[xcode 6 beta 2 issue with exporting ipa "Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438010/xcode-6-beta-2-issue-with-exporting-ipa-your-account-already-has-a-valid-ios-di)

[Xcode 6 App Store submission fails with "Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717994/xcode-6-app-store-submission-fails-with-your-account-already-has-a-valid-ios-di)

[Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate from same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122888/your-account-already-has-a-valid-ios-distribution-certificate-from-same-machine)

I delete all my Provisioning Profile and certificate and add them manually as well as using Xcode also but none worked, getting this error all time.

I also tried to archive in Xcode 6.4 and export it using Xcode 5 but that `.ipa` not able to installed on my iPad.

I want to generate `.ipa`, but with each solution I got this error every time. Please help!

Comment: You need export your account from old mac and import it to new mac.

Comment: i delete my account from xcode and add it again.but not worked.

Comment: I got the same problem, bro.

Comment: This seems to be a workable answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651758/your-account-already-has-a-valid-developer-id-application-certificate

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717994/xcode-6-app-store-submission-fails-with-your-account-already-has-a-valid-ios-di