# Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate certificate

Tags: ios, xcode

[image: I have never logged in to another mac even though i am getting this erroe, as i have never logged in any other mac than export account option mentioned below is not valid for me.]

[Your account already has a valid Developer ID Application certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651758/your-account-already-has-a-valid-developer-id-application-certificate)

Comment: getting this error please help me.

Comment: i have single mac machine only, i am using the same for my another app upload to app store.

Comment: What is your question? What is the difference from the linked question?

Comment: click on the link its the same questions that i had .... but couldnt understnd what he is saying.... please check both

Answer (score 1):

F.Y.I.

The error is saying that certificate that you have installed in you mac is duplicate or created on another system so remove it from your current mac and find it out where actual that created *(Means it is created on another mac)* so export it from and make new **.p12** file and install it on your current mac. Hope your error will be vanished.

OR

Another option already available in the link that you have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!!! i am beginner to this iPhone build process. i am not clear about the distribution certificate do you mean provisioning profile?

Comment: Do you mean CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest? Or *.mobileprovision